# Can I add this in my resume?

Tags: resume, work-environment

I have done a small project(or just a shell script). It takes the youtube videos links from a text file, downloads them using youtube-dl. and I have croned this shell script to run from mid night 12am till 8am morning.(I have free downloads at night.) Though this is not a very great project, does it make sense if I add this in resume? (I have around 8 months of experience in IT industry.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should touch this in your resume. But NOT HIGHLIGHTED! This will ensure that you have some knowledge in programming.

Comment: okay, I will add it but not highlight it.  Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: It might be a special achievement for yourself, but for a company, they want people who had worked in real project with a client. (Up and running system may be) I guess you had written a program. Not a software. That's why i told  JUST to mention it to let them to know that you are capable in programming even though you haven't done this in a real project.

Comment: I agree that this isn't a great project. I guess this small piece of code says I know shell scripting , awk command, crontabs, etc . this is why I want to add this in resume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless it's a project you can boast about(like a big project for a client, or an open source project with many users) I wouldn't mention the *specific* project itself in the resume. Instead, try to write the more general categories the project belong to:

- Created shell scripts that interact with web services
- Automated background tasks with cron

I don't know what the role you are trying to apply to is or what the company does, but I can only assume that someone that knows how to automate tasks that interact with web services can be more useful to them than someone who can download videos from youtube.